# UITableView IndexPath.row out of scope

Tags: iphone, objective-c, tableview

I am implementing the following tableview method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

The problem is, when  this gets hit, indexpath.row is showing up as out of scope.  I am trying to handle the delete button for this row so I can delete the cell and delete the value out of the tableview's datasource.

Answer (score 0):

What you are seeing is xCode's debugger being goofy.  This happens a bunch.  What I do is make a local variable like this and set my breakpoint there and the debugger will act better.

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSIndexPath temp = indexPath; //Set Debugger after this and you can inspect the variable.
}
```